# HerokuのDjangoプロジェクトをデプロイしたい

Tags: python, django, heroku

http://qiita.com/nakazye/items/48651e39f07da82fe79e

上のサイトを参考にしてHerokuにデプロイできたのですが､Application Errorでサイトが表示できません｡  いろいろ試しましたが､解決方法がわかりませんでした｡  どうすればサイトを表示できるのでしょうか｡  教えて下さい｡  以下に`settings.py`を示します｡

```
import os
from django.conf.global_settings import LANGUAGE_CODE, TIME_ZONE,\
    STATICFILES_DIRS, STATIC_ROOT
import dj_database_url
from socket import gethostname
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = 'staticfiles'

hostname = gethostname()

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@71lbdkiwo_wf!)h0og^#z022$48#7=_9ldccg^(=zb&219640'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
#デバッグモードをするか判定
if 'VAIO' in hostname:
    DEBUG = True
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True
else:
    DEBUG = False
    TEMPLATE_DEBUG = False
    ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrapform',
    'cms',
    'gunicorn',
    'whitenoise',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'homesecurity.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'homesecurity.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases
#データベースをどれにするか判定
if 'VAIO' in hostname:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
            'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),   
        }
    }
else:
    import dj_database_url
    DATABASES = {
        'default': dj_database_url.config()
    }

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ja'

TIME_ZONE = 'Asia/Tokyo'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
```

`Heroku logs`でのログは以下のようになっていました｡

```
[32m2015-03-15T00:10:11.273938+00:00 heroku[router]:[0m at=error code=H14 desc
="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=pacific-headland-1022.herok
uapp.com request_id=3d77730f-7e43-42d1-b5a3-83e20b90ab14 fwd="119.105.221.203" d
yno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: Error に "No web processes running" とあります．`$ heroku ps` の結果はどうなりますか（プロセスが止まっているというようなことはありませんか？）

Comment: `heroku ps`を実行したのですが｡何も表示されませんでした｡

Answer (score 1, accepted):

参考になるかはわかりませんが、一度DebugをTrueにしてみてはどうでしょうか？
Django側のエラーでなければHerokuのDeploy方法で何かミスがあるかもしれません。
以下のサイトはDjango Girlsというサイトですが、HerokuをDeploy先としているチュートリアルです。(Django1.7)
http://tutorial.djangogirls.org/en/django_urls/README.html
このサイト通り実行すれば、HerokuにDeployできると思います。
もし何か詰まってもGitterにいけばChat形式で教えてくれると思います。
https://gitter.im/DjangoGirls/tutorial

何かヒントに慣れば幸いです^^

Comment: ありがとう御座います｡  サイトの通り実行したところできました!!

Comment: お役に立てて良かったです ^^